# When double-clicking on a word, highlight every occurrence of this word in the Aptana 3 text editor

Tags: aptana3

Good morning.

With Aptana 2, a very useful function was the automatic hightlighting of the selected word : when double-clicking on a variable name, function name, ... (on a word), Aptana 2 automatically highlight this word in the document.

Why it was really useful : in the description of a function, when clicking on a variable declaration, if the variable is used, I can immediately see where.

With Aptana 3, I've lost this function.   No doubt that I can configure the editor but I can't find where.

Comment: Is there somebody who can help ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

It might be a bit late, but I missed that too and I just found out how to activate it:
http://www.screencast.com/t/CjZOtMgwe

Just needed to click on the highlight (Mark Occurrences) icon on top of the editor.